# What is the Big O of Neo4j's REDUCE Fuction

Tags: neo4j, reduce, shortest-path, bigdata

I'm pretty new to Neo4j and am looking into using it as a solution.  Consider this example: [Finding the Shortest Path through the Park](https://neo4j.com/blog/finding-the-shortest-path-through-the-park/)

What is the Big O notation of the REDUCE function in Neo4j?  Does it calculate each possibility and rank them or is it more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `REDUCE` function simply iterates through the items in a collection, performing for each item an arbitrary operation that returns a value, retaining the latest value, and ultimately returning the last value.

If we ignore the complexity of the "arbitrary operation" itself, the complexity of the `REDUCE` function is `O(N)`, where `N` is the size of the collection.

Comment: I assumed O(N) but was hoping for better - but I don't know why it would be better.

Comment: The complexity for iterating though N items is always O(N). If you are hoping for something faster, you  should not be using `REDUCE`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are referring to this query

```
START  startNode=node:node_auto_index(name="Start"),
             endNode=node:node_auto_index(name="Finish")
MATCH  p=(startNode)-[:NAVIGATE_TO*]->(endNode)
RETURN p AS shortestPath,
                reduce(distance=0, r in relationships(p) :  distance+r.distance) AS totalDistance
ORDER BY totalDistance ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

first you define your start and end node... and match all paths between them...

```
RETURN p AS shortestPath,
reduce(distance=0, r in relationships(p) :  distance+r.distance) AS totalDistance
ORDER BY totalDistance ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

this `reduce` works like this it extracts all the distance properties from the relationships of the path and sums them up. So if you `order by` results ascending by distance and `limit` it to 1, you get only the first smallest distance

p.s. i think the big O you are referring is actually a zero 0, so that it starts for every path from zero and add up all distances